# Curl, mod_auth_openidc, and mod_oauth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I'm very new to OpenID Connect and OAuth2, so please bear with me.

I have mod_auth_openidc and mod_oauth2 set up on an Apache web server with AD as my authentication server, and am trying to figure out how to authenticate to the web site with curl (or any other programatic interface). I understand how you can call the authentication server directly while passing the the client secret, but it seems to me that it would be better to have the web server keep the secret, and have curl hit a URI on the web server that would cause the appropriate flow to happen. Is this doable, or does the curl command have to do all of the work?

I have tried going to a URI protected with mod_auth_openidc, but that just redirects me to my AD login page.

Comment: I think it depends on whether you are using and SPA or regular Web Application. A WebApplication will keep the secret on the web server where the pages are rendered. An SPA will  use the PKCE flow.

Comment: It is a PHP application making the curl call using the Client URL library.